# Can you improve the detection accuracy of neural-network based human detection programs (Such as Caffe) through further training?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I have access to a large database of network cameras. Would it be possible for me to make caffe have a better detection rate on these cameras if I train with these cameras?

My gut says no because although at an angle and slightly more blurry, the images I can get for training
are very similar to the images used in initially training Caffe (PASCAL VOC 2007).

I am undertaking a project which would need me to make thousands of labels for training and testing
and am wondering if I am wasting my time.

On a different note, what about per camera training? If I were to train per camera would that improve my 
detection rate? This seems a bit more viable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, using more training data should improve your accuracy. But if they are similar to the PASCAL VOC, then I'd expect that the improvement won't be much.

I think per camera training should improve the accuracy as we can learn the intricacies in the data for that camera (angle, noise, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Training on the same dataset has a higher chance of resulting in a more accurate model. The same goes for training per camera as you might see similar poses in each camera.

However, in order to train a working model, you need a huge labeled dataset which takes more time than you expect.